# How to get only the cropped portion of an image in python

Tags: python, image, numpy

I need to crop a polygon from an image. I have used PIL. I can get the cropped image, but while I read the cropped polygon for further calculation, it reads the hole image not the cropped portion. I need to get only the cropped portion.
here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
im = Image.open("input.jpg").convert("RGBA")
imArray = np.asarray(im)

polygon=[cropping points]
#print(polygon)
print(imArray.shape)
maskIm = Image.new('L', (imArray.shape[1], imArray.shape[0]), 0)
ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=1)
mask = np.array(maskIm)

newImArray = np.empty(imArray.shape, dtype='uint8')

newImArray[:, :, :3] = imArray[:, :, :3]
#print(newImArray)
newImArray[:, :, 3] = mask * 255

newIm = Image.fromarray(newImArray, "RGBA")
newIm.save("out.png","PNG")
```

Comment: From a cursory glance the code looks OK, but you did not post a [minimal, *complete*, and *verifiable* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I cannot run your code and check. What do you mean by "read the cropped polygon for further calculation"? Does the saved image look how you expect (everything in the polygon opaque, everything outside of the polygon transparent)? Currently you're *not* cropping the image. You need to define a subregion (roi, or *region of interest*) of the image which contains only the polygon and save that.

Comment: If the polygon simple contains points, then the min and max x and y values of all the points will give you the region the polygon is contained in. Then you can simply make the ROI that height and width, and index the original image and mask at those points.

Comment: After saving the cropped image it looks like how I expected in any image viewer. But when I use cv2.imread() and use matplotlib.show() it shows the complete image, not the cropped portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the PIL [ImageDraw docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html), it looks like polygons are normally referenced with a list of `(x, y)` tuples. What you need to do is find the bounds of your polygon and define a region of interest around those bounds in your original image and mask. Then you can simply create an array with the size of your region, and insert the image/mask from those found boundaries.

A polygon never extends *past* the points you define, so finding the minimum and maximum (x, y) values will define your region of interest. I believe the following should work for you, with the above in mind the code is pretty self-explanatory.

```
polygon = [(25, 67), (82, 90), (50, 22)]
min_x, min_y = np.min(polygon, axis=0)
max_x, max_y = np.max(polygon, axis=0)
h, w = max_y - min_y, max_x - min_x

newImArray = np.empty((h, w, 4), dtype='uint8')

newImArray[:, :, :3] = imArray[min_y:max_y, min_x:max_x, :3]
newImArray[:, :, 3] = mask[min_y:max_y, min_x:max_x] * 255

newIm = Image.fromarray(newImArray, "RGBA")
newIm.save("out.png","PNG")
```